# WSGI application error kills screen session and generates hash error in python package

Tags: 20.04, package-management, python, screen

I have searched a lot before but couldn't find a solution for a problem I'm facing with a screen session in a Ubuntu 20.04 VM.

In this VM I have a pypi-server configured to host a python package. I should be able to install this python package in a local env using a pip install command. It was working until I had update the source code, to include versioning.

After I included the versioning in the package and tested in my machine (everything was fine) I pushed it to the repository on my branch and them, pulled the remote copy of the package with these new features.

Once I made it, I generated a sdist, bdist and tar.gz with `python setup.py`, I 've checked the generated packages on the dist folder and them copied the tar.gz to a folder called packages, used for the screen.

I followed all these steps but when I tried to install the package locally on my machine I received this message:

```
ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
    package from http://00.000.000.000:8090/packages/package-x.x.x.tar.gz#md5=0bc256477dc39af8f5e0fd5c3bfba88e:
        Expected md5 0bc256477dc39af8f5e0fd5c3bfba88e
             Got        8f1cfff4716df907cb98654420f9c566
```

(I have omitted sensible information)

Well, after receiving this error I checked the screen session it presented this description:

```
WSGI application error
Killed
```

Does anybody knows what might be going on? If something is not clear I can provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question because maybe this can be useful to someone else in the future.

I am not 100% sure which of the 3 things I've done was the real solution for the problem, but, basically,I did this:

- Rebooted the VM;
- Created a new tmux session to host the pypi server;
- Chenged the final number of the version, so the version I was facing problems was x.x.3, I made a downgrade in the final number (the main package code was exactly the same as before adding versioning) to x.x.2.

After these changes it worked as expected.